# Facebook text share not working with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller, iphone-6

*Well, the situation is when I am trying to share text in facebook with UIActivityViewController, the share text shows blank in the facebook popup whereas the URL  provided comes but text doesn't show in Facebook share dialog or popup. **One more thing sometimes the URL also don't come or show in share dialog.***

**NOTE:**

**Facebook native app is already installed in device and logged in from device settings, I have also updated the  app to version 31.0.**

**Device used:- iPhone 6 with iOS 8.3**

---

---

**Code:-**

```
    NSString *shareString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome to family."];
    NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    NSArray *shareArray = @[shareString,website];



    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:shareArray
                                                                                    applicationActivities:nil];




    [self presentViewController:activityController
                       animated:YES completion:nil];

    [activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){

    }];
```

---

---

Comment: You are aware that the user needs to write the text?

Comment: @WizKid- I think you have overlooked my question, I am already passing the text which will be shared and I already know user can update it in the share dialog as per his/her requirement.So It will be better if you can give some time reading the question before commenting :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't work if you have the newest Facebook app installed - the text always  blank and sometimes URL doesn't show in facebook version 31.0 . This share feature only works older app means version less than 28..